# Jquery working with name attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code that uses html img controls and change their size when I hover
the problem is that every "img" in window is affected by this.

My question is how do I change my code so it will only relate to spacific images,

**please see my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGNCY/)**
*jquery code*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var cont_left = $("#container").position().left;
$("a img").hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.img').css('z-index', 1);

    var orig = $this.data('orig');
    if (!orig) { // caching the original sizes via `jQuery.data`
        orig = {
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height
        };
        $this.data('orig', orig);
    }
    $this.stop(true, false).animate({
        width: orig.width * 1.3,
        height: orig.height * 1.3,
        left: -(orig.width * 0.3 / 2),
        top: -(orig.height * 0.3 / 2)
    }, 300);
}, function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        orig = $this.data('orig');
    if (!orig) {
        return false;
        // should never be here, as it means calling 'mouseleave' without 'mouseenter'
    }
    $this.closest('.img').css('z-index', 0);
    // hover out
    $this.stop(true, false).animate({
        width: orig.width,
        height: orig.height,
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    }, 300);
});
$(".img").each(function (index) {
    var left = (index * 160) + cont_left;
    $(this).css("left", left + "px");
});
});
```

**Can I use a name attribute? Or something other than "img" ?**

Comment: Use classes instead and target them like $(".className")

Comment: @RickyStam At this point I've stolen your thunder, but IMHO that's an answer, not a comment, next time you should get credit for it!

Comment: Thank you!, can you change my fiddle ?

Comment: I already changed it see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AGNCY/1/)

CSS:

```
<img id='first' src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" width="350" />
```

JS:

```
var cont_left = $("#container").position().left;
$("img#first").hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.img').css('z-index', 1);

var orig = $this.data('orig');
if (!orig) { // caching the original sizes via `jQuery.data`
    orig = {
    width: this.width,
    height: this.height
    };
    $this.data('orig', orig);
}
$this.stop(true, false).animate({
    width: orig.width * 1.3,
    height: orig.height * 1.3,
    left: -(orig.width * 0.3 / 2),
    top: -(orig.height * 0.3 / 2)
}, 300);
```

You can find more information about jQuery selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

Comment: I would point your link to the actual JQuery site, instead of W3Schools.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Give it a class ".class" selector, or an ID.

"a img" selects any image with a link somewhere above it in the DOM, which is why it's stretching farther than you are expecting it to.

**HTML**:

```
<img class="selectMe" src="ponies.jpg" />
```

**ECMAScript**

```
$(".selectMe").hover(function(){  doStuff();};
```

For reference you should check out this guy: 
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/